# How to display on the web page a picture that I saved in the storage on firebase? (with angular8)

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to display on my web page a picture that I saved in the storage on firebase.
Background: I created a folder called "photos" in the storage, and put there a file named "dog.jpg".
I got help from the site: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start
Then I wrote in the angular code (in app.component.ts):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
//for firestore we added these 2 imports
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
//for firestore documents:
import { AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
//for firestore documents:
export interface Item { name: string; }
//for storage:
import { AngularFireStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl:`
  <p>app component</p> 
  <img src={{spaceRef}}/>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  // Get a reference to the storage service, which is used to create references in your storage bucket
  public storage = firebase.storage();
  // Create a storage reference from our storage 
  storageRef = this.storage.ref();
  spaceRef = this.storageRef.child('photos/dog.jpg');
  // spaceRef now points to "photos/dog.jpg"
}
```

When I run the code, "Cannot GET /" is written on the web page.
and on the terminal:

```
 ERROR in HostResourceResolver: could not resolve 
  <p>app component</p> 
  <img src={{spaceRef}}/>
```

Can you please help me locate the problem? Thanks!:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I must say I didn't look what caused your problem. Tried to do the same as you while following the documentation. Think the main difference between what I did and what you do, is injecting AngularFireStorage.

TS

```
  imageUrl$: Observable<string>;
  constructor(private storage: AngularFireStorage) {
    this.imageUrl$ = storage.ref("test.png").getDownloadURL();
  }
```

HTML

```
<img [src]="imageUrl$ | async">
```

Here you have a working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-firebase-image-test)

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I tried it, but it didn't solve the problem. Do you think I need to add something to the AppComponent class?

Comment: I would expect a different error. I'll make a stackblitz to test

Answer (score 3):

For img tag, you need to have a URL instead of a storage reference. You can get the download URL for a file by calling the getDownloadURL() method on a storage reference.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
//for firestore we added these 2 imports
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
//for firestore documents:
import { AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
//for firestore documents:
export interface Item { name: string; }
//for storage:
import { AngularFireStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl:`
  <p>app component</p> 
  <img src="{{spaceRef}}"/>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  // Get a reference to the storage service, which is used to create references in your storage bucket
  public storage = firebase.storage();
  // Create a storage reference from our storage 
  storageRef = this.storage.ref();
  spaceRef = "";
  // spaceRef is now empty 
  constructor(){
      this.storageRef.child('photos/dog.jpg').getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
           this.spaceRef = url;
           // spaceRef now points to URL of "photos/dog.jpg"
      };
  }
}
```

For additional information: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url

Comment: You're missing a call to `.getDownloadURL()` in the `constructor`.